# Behaviour to un/hide Framework Element

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have created a custom `TextBlock` that changes the `Visibility` after some seconds specified by a `DependencyProperty` `ShowTime`:

```
<customUserControl:AutoHideTextBlock Text="AutoHideTextBlock" Visibility="{Binding IsVisibleEnabled, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}" ShowTime="3"/>
```

This is a nice solution and it works, the problem is that I have several other elements that needs the same behaviour and I cannot really make it a `CustomUserControl` for all of them, I have created the following class to help me with that:

```
public class AutoHideExtension
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty VisibilityListenerProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "VisibilityListener",
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(AutoHideExtension),
            new PropertyMetadata(false, VisibilityChanged));

    public static double GetVisibilityListener(DependencyObject obj)
        => (double)obj.GetValue(VisibilityListenerProperty);

    public static void SetVisibilityListener(DependencyObject obj, double value)
        => obj.SetValue(VisibilityListenerProperty, value);

    private static void VisibilityChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var element = (FrameworkElement)d;

        if (element.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed || !IsLoaded)
            {
                return;
            }

        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.Background)
                                    {
                                        Interval =
                                            new TimeSpan(
                                            0,
                                            0,
                                            ShowTime)
                                    };

        timer.Tick += (senderEvent, args) =>
            {
                element.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                timer.Stop();
            };

        timer.Start();
    }
}
```

The idea is that I can attach this new property to any element and change the visibility after the specified time, something like follows:

```
<TextBlock Text="TextToHide"
            helpers:AutoHideExtension.VisibilityListener="{Binding ChangesSavedEnabled}"/>
```

The problem is that I don't know how to specify the `ShowTime` as property in the extension class, and that this is simply not working since is not changing the `Visibility`.

Any Ideas or suggestions on how I can continue forward with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Define another attached property for the ShowTime.

Comment: I tried already, but it says cannot access to `GetValue` or `SetValue`, Do I have to inherit from any special object?

Comment: Your dependency property VisibilityListener should get and set a bool value, and not a double.

Comment: Do you need the time as a property or is it really a set value like 5 seconds or something?

Comment: :facepalm: good point @mm8, that solve the part that was not working regarding the `Visibility` but I still cannot create a DP to set the ShowTime property

Comment: Not really @andy,  but I would like to learn, I can set a default value of 3 or 5 seconds and the work is done, but I do not learn anything =D

Comment: I was thinking you could use a converter frameworkelement and bind visibility. You can put a property on that which can be set - but not bound.

Comment: What about `Behavior` for this case?

Comment: @Nekeniehl: Just copy the first one and change the type to `int`? See my answer about Blend behaviours by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dependency property `VisibilityListener` should get and set a `bool` value:

```
public static bool GetVisibilityListener(DependencyObject obj)
    => (bool)obj.GetValue(VisibilityListenerProperty);

public static void SetVisibilityListener(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    => obj.SetValue(VisibilityListenerProperty, value);
```

You could then define another attached property for the ShowTime, or you could define a [Blend behaviour](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/01/30/wpf-using-behaviours-to-bind-to-readonly-properties-in-mvvm/) that contains two properties:

```
<TextBlock xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
          Text="TextToHide">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:AutoHideExtensionBehavior VisibilityListener="{Binding ChangesSavedEnabled}" ShowTime="3" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: What do  you think is the way to go on MVVM? I believe behaviours right?

Comment: @Nekeniehl: Attached behaviours and Blend behaviours both fit into MVVM. Which approach to use depends on your requirements. Blend behaviours cannot be used in style setters for example, but they do provide better encapsulation.